# Error: scalac: error while loading package, Scala signature package has wrong version; expected 5.0, found 5.2 in package.class

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I have a java & scala project that I am updating jars for.

I swapped out `akka-camel_2.11.jar` and replaced it with jar `akka-camel_2.13-2.5.25.jar`, and now I see the error shown in the title when attempting to build in Intellij.

What is the `scala signature`? What is `package.class`?
And how might I edit these so that my project can build using this updated jar?

Comment: You shouldn't be updating versions of dependencies of a project that you do not understand its technologies. Because **Scala** does not guarantee binary compability between their major versions, **Scala** libraries have to be recompiled and republished for each **Scala** major version they want to support, and the **Scala** version is added to the name of the jar, thus `akka-camel_2.11` means that the **Scala** version for which that dependency was compiles was **Scala** `2.11`, when you changed that to `akka-camel_2.13` you break binary compability, that is the `scala signature`.

Comment: Additionally, putting the **Scala** version manually in the dependency is a bad practice. If the projects uses **SBT** you should use the `%%` when declaring the dependency, so it uses the correct one. If you are using **Maven** or **Gradle** you should always refer to variable which contains the correct version.

Answer (score 11):

When you have multiple versions of dependencies of same SDK it show this error
I too faced this issue.
my scala project had the following dependencies
org.scala-lang:scala-library.2.11.0 [as well as]
org.scala-lang:scala-library.2.7.0

so this caused the confusion with the signature.

remove one of the added library .
in intellij idea
files -> project structure -> library tab -> scroll and search for the extra added library  -> press the '-' icon at top left side of the dialog box.

Comment: After looking for a few hours. this was what finally fixed my setup. I had set up a Global Scala SDK, not realizing that it is supplied by my pom.xml....